# Ring Buffer on C

Tags: c

I just started learning C language. Now my task is to write a simple ring buffer.
I wrote a code but it doesn't work. I can't solve the problem, obviously, I indicated wrong parameters in push and pop functions. It's needed to use head, tail and size of the buffer (the problem is in tail i think but can't properly get).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ringBuffer 
{
    void *bufferData;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
    int numElements;
};

void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int size) 
{
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->head = 0;
    buffer->tail = 0;
    buffer->numElements = 0;
    buffer->bufferData = (void*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
}

void bufferFree(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    free(buffer->bufferData);
}

int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int *data)
{

    /*  int i;
    i = buffer->head + buffer->tail + 1;
    if (i >= buffer->size) 
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    buffer->bufferData[i] = data;*/
    memcpy((void*)buffer->head, data, buffer->size);
    buffer->head = buffer->head + buffer->size;
    if (buffer->head == buffer->tail)
    { 
        buffer->head = (int)buffer->bufferData; //error?
    }
    buffer->numElements++;
    return 0;
}

int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer, void *data)
{
    //void * bufferData;

    /*bufferData = buffer->bufferData[buffer->head];
    buffer->head++;
    buffer->tail--;
    if (buffer->head == buffer->size) 
    {
        buffer->head = 0;
    }
    //return bufferData;*/

    memcpy(data, (void*)buffer->tail, buffer->size); //error?
    buffer->tail = buffer->tail + buffer->size;

    if ((void*)buffer->tail == buffer->bufferData)
    { 
        buffer->tail = (int)buffer->bufferData; //error?
    }
    buffer->numElements--;
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    struct ringBuffer buffer;
    int size = 5;
    //*buffer->size = 6;
    bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
    char *data[] = { "1" , "2", "3", "4" , "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Push: data[%d] = %s\n", i, *data[i]);
        pushBack(&buffer, (int*)data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("PushBack: queue[%d] = %s\n", i, (ringBuffer*)popFront(&buffer, (void*)data[i])); // !!!
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("PopFront: data[%d] = %s\n", i, *data[i]);
        pushBack(&buffer, (int*)data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for any help and advices!

Comment: Did you solve the problem on paper before writing your code?

Comment: 1) Write a couple of unit tests that would show your program is operating correctly. 2) Debug said unit tests when they fail so you can find and fix your logic errors. 3) Profit

Comment: "Debug my code" is not on topic here. You debug it and then you tell us what the problem is. Show what it does and what it should do instead. Preferably with a minimal, complete and verifyable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why are you storing a `void *`in your structure when your initialization code assumes you are dealing with `int`?  It makes your code spuriously generic and complicates your manipulation of the data.  To be generic, you must accept the element size as part of the data about the buffer.  But given that you're having problems, you'd do better to go non-generic first.  Get that working, the genericize the code.

Comment: You might need to start with an empty working program, and then build it up in small manageable steps that you understand.

Comment: You have to tell push and pop, how many bytes to read and write. 
You need the 'used' bytes instead of numElements. The writeable size is `size - used`. But you have to test for wrap around. If `size` is 100 and `head` is 90 you can only write 10 bytes at position `head`, then you have to wrap around ( head=0 ) and then write the other 80 bytes. Pop has the same problem. You always have to test for wrap around the tail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffle I fixed that, hope it seems nice now. Don't really get when I should use int and void functions. Int has to return some valuse (0 if it's right and !=0 if the function is wrong).

Comment: @Holger I corrected my code and added another one member of the structure.

Comment: @AndyG I have an exception when debugging in main function where I'm trying to use pushBack function.

Comment: Thank you all guys. Now my code looks like that.

Comment: @EgorZvyagintsev: What is `memcpy((void*)buffer->head, data, buffer->size);` supposed to do?

Comment: I looked at the revised code and then realized I'd got no clue whether you're trying to store strings or integers in your ring buffer.  Some parts of the code seem to expect integers (`buffer->bufferData = (void*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);` for example).  Other parts might be expecting strings: `printf("Push: data[%d] = %s\n", i, *data[i]); pushBack(&buffer, (int*)data[i]);`).  Other parts are just bizarre: `printf("PushBack: queue[%d] = %s\n", i, (ringBuffer*)popFront(&buffer, (void*)data[i]));` — that is not going to work well and won't compile for me (I tell the compiler to be fussy).

Comment: @AndyG It's supposed to copy our datas (from array in main function) to the beginning of head using size of buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I decided to use only 4 values in buffer structure, it seems it works well. In the end of the code there is a dataBuffer check.

Now I need to write a printBuffer function just to show values in dataBuffer from HEAD to TAIL but I noticed a problem: everytime I write a values in the buffer, the difference between HEAD and TAIL is always 1 (as I understood when buffer is empty, size = 8 and there are only 6 values in data[], it has to be shown like bufferData[0] = 1 ... bufferData[5] = 6 but as result in works incorrectly.Could you explain me please how to bring the function printBuffer to acceptable form?

Thanks. Here is my code (it works and there are checking everywhere):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ringBuffer
{
    int *bufferData;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
};

void bufferFree(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    free(buffer->bufferData);
}

void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int size)
{
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->head = 0;
    buffer->tail = 0;
    buffer->bufferData = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}

void printBuffer(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int i, int size)
{
    printf("Values from HEAD to TAIL: ");
    if (buffer->head == buffer->tail)
    {
        printf("Head and tail are equals\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("bufferData[%d] = %d\n", i, buffer->bufferData);
    }
}

int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int data)
{
    buffer->bufferData[buffer->tail++] = data;
    if (buffer->tail == buffer->size)
    {
        buffer->tail = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    if (buffer->head != buffer->tail)
    {
        buffer->head++;
        if (buffer->head == buffer->size)
        {
            buffer->head = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct ringBuffer buffer;
    int size = 8;
    int data[] = { 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 }; // 20 values
    int dataSize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);

    /* Test implimention with 1 element in dataBuffer */
    bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
    printf("Head : %d - Tail: %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 5);
    printf("Head : %d - Tail: %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    popFront(&buffer);
    printf("Head : %d - Tail: %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    printf("\nnumElements in data = %d : bufferSize = %d\n\n", dataSize, size);
    bufferFree(&buffer);

    /* Implimention with dada[] */
    printf("INITIALIZATION\n");
    bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
    printf("Head : %d - Tail: %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);

    /* pushBack call */
    printf("\nPUSHBACK\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        pushBack(&buffer, data[i]);
        printf("Head : %d - Tail : %d :: Data = %d (data[%d])   \n", buffer.head, buffer.tail, data[i], i);
        /*for (int k = buffer.head; k<=buffer.tail; k++)
        { 
            // Print methode from head to tail
            printBuffer((ringBuffer*)buffer.bufferData, i, size);
        }*/
        popFront(&buffer);
    }
    popFront(&buffer);
    printf("Head : %d - Tail : %d :: (popFront)\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    /* bufferData check */
    printf("\nbufferData check:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] = %d  ", i, buffer.bufferData[i]);
    }
    printf("\nHead : %d - Tail : %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    bufferFree(&buffer);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ringBuffer 
{
    char *bufferData;
    void *bufferEnd;

    int head;
    int tail;

    int size;
    int used;
    int capacity; // "вместимость"
};

void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int capacity, int size) 
{
    buffer->bufferData = (char*)malloc(capacity * size);
    if (buffer->bufferData == 0)
    { 
        buffer->bufferEnd = (char *)buffer->bufferData + capacity * size;
    }
    buffer->capacity = capacity;
    buffer->used = 0;
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->head = *buffer->bufferData;
    buffer->tail = *buffer->bufferData;
}

void bufferFree(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    free(buffer->bufferData);
}

int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, char *data)
{
    if (buffer->used == buffer->capacity) {
        printf("Capacity error\n");
        buffer->bufferData = 0; //??
    }
    memcpy((ringBuffer*)buffer->head, data, buffer->size);
    buffer->head = buffer->head + buffer->size;
    if (buffer->head == (char)buffer->bufferEnd)
    {
        buffer->head = (char)buffer->bufferData;
    }
    buffer->used++;
    return 0;
}

int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer, char *data)
{
    if (buffer->used == 0) 
    {
        printf("Buffer is clear\n");
    }
    memcpy(data, (ringBuffer*)buffer->tail, buffer->size); 
    buffer->tail = (char)buffer->tail + buffer->size;
    if (buffer->tail == (char)buffer->bufferEnd)
    {
        buffer->tail = (char)buffer->bufferData;
    }
    buffer->used--;
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    struct ringBuffer buffer;
    int size = 6;
    int capacity = 10;
    bufferInitialization(&buffer, capacity, size);
    char *data[] = { "1" , "2", "3", "4" , "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Push: data[%d] = %d\n", i, *data[i]);
        pushBack(&buffer, (char*)data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("PushBack: queue[%d] = %s\n", i, (ringBuffer*)popFront(&buffer, (char*)data[i])); // !!!
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("PopFront: data[%d] = %s : %s\n", i, *data[i]);
        pushBack(&buffer, (char*)data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You only need size, not capacity and size. You need the size of the data in pushBack. You can't memcpy buffer->size bytes if data only contains "a". After memcpy you increment buffer->head by size of data. Before  you memcpy, you must check, if buffer->size - buffer->head is >= data size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample without memcpy. So you cann see the problem with the buffer end while copying. It's not tested but shows how you can go on. It's a `char` ringbuffer, so you have to write chars. There is no check for `\0`, so your size must include them if you read and write "strings".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ringBuffer 
{
    char *bufferData;
    char *head;
    char *tail;
    char *end;
    int size;
    int free;
};

void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int size) 
{
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->used = 0;
    buffer->head = 
    buffer->tail =
    buffer->bufferData = malloc(size);
    buffer->end  = buffer->bufferData + size;
}

int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, char *data, int size)
{
    if(size > buffer->size - buffer->used) return -1;

    for( ; size>0 && buffer->used < buffer->size; buffer->used++, size--) {
        *buffer->head = *data;
        buffer->head++;
        data++;
        if(buffer->head == buffer->end) buffer->head = buffer->bufferData;
    }
    return 0;
}

int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer, char *data, int size)
{
    if(size > buffer->used) return -1;

    for( ; size>0 && buffer->used > 0; buffer->used--, size--) {
        *data = *buffer->tail;
        buffer->tail++;
        data++;
        if(buffer->tail == buffer->end) buffer->tail = buffer->bufferData;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do we use pointers for head and tail? And the same question for "end"
@Holger

Comment: @EgorZvyagintsev You probably figured it out long ago, but there are multiple ways to implement a circular / ring buffer. Sometimes I use a fixed-length array so then the head and tail can be indices (`size_t` or whatever) and end becomes redundant with size (suits some of my embedded problems nicely). The important thing is that `head` and `tail` refer to positions in the buffer (i.e. memory locations!) so will most naturally be pointers. The Wikipedia entry has a nice visual for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#/media/File:Circular_Buffer_Animation.gif